# Hide GridView Image Column if Database value is Null

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, datagridview

I have a Gridview which has an image column to the right side.When the user checks a checkbox only those items with a non Null Image should be displayed.

I have seen that the Gridview uses the default Image if the database image corresponding to the row is empty.Will i need to write a new stored procedure for this or is there a better way to do it.

I currently have implemented this

```
try
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        dgvGetData.Columns["image"].Visible = true;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvGetData.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LOOP");
            if (row.Cells[16].Value == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("######################################> NULL");
                row.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("######################################> NOT NULL");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dgvGetData.Columns["image"].Visible = false;
    }
}
catch (Exception error)
{
    MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you use the `CellFormatting` event handler.  You can write a few lines of code to determine if you're on the correct column and then have it display whatever you want.

Here is a partial example:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value == null && dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Image")
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellformattingeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx